# How do I add information into the text file during execution? C

Tags: c, file

I have edited my code because of fear that someone from the same course as me would copy my code and hand it in.  Thanks for the answer you have given me, its a great help.

My program should allow me to add the new item into the system along with its name, price and quantity.
But during execution, my code seems to damage the file. I have no idea what's wrong and would not like to write a more complicated code. 
The program just skip the quantity and return to the menu. Not allowing me to input the quantity .

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string,h>

struct Item//declaring a structure
{
char code[25];//variables inside a structure
char name[25];
double price;
int quantity;
};

int main (void)
{
struct Item item;
FILE *fgst;

printf("-------------------------------\n");
printf("    ADD PRODUCT\n");
printf("-------------------------------\n");

    fgst = fopen("gst.txt", "r"); 
    if(fgst==NULL)
    {
        printf("File cannot be found\n");

    }
    else //else statement
    {
        printf("Add Code:\n");
        scanf("%s", item.code);
        printf("name:\n");
        scanf("%s", item.name);
        printf("price:\n");
        scanf("%.2f",&item.price);
        printf("quantity:\n");
        scanf("%d", &item.quantity);

        fprintf(fgst,"%s;%s;%.2f;%d\n",item.code,item.name,item.price,item.quantity);
    fclose(fgst);
    }//end else statement
    break;
    }
```

The content of the one of the file is as follow:

AS520;Jelly tartar;5.35;42

Comment: Please use the debugger to identify the source of the crash.

Comment: Take the compiler's warnings serious. Fix the code until no more warnings are issued. Do not blindy "cast" away error messages.

Comment: If you want to open a file to append data to it, use `"a"`, not `"r"`!

Comment: Please don't "fix" the code in the question text!! Anyone who comes later with a similar problem will wonder what the issue was and what all the answers are talking about, and they will not get any help.

Comment: @Kusalananda okay, the problem code  is still in the question

Answer (score 0):

From the `man scanf`:

The scanf() family of functions scans input according to format as described below. This format may contain conversion specifications; the results from such conversions, if any, are stored in the locations pointed to by the **pointer arguments** that follow format.

The following statements are wrong:

```
    scanf("%.2f",product.price);
    scanf("%d", product.quantity);
```

They should have had the following form:

```
    scanf("%.2f",&(product.price));
    scanf("%d", &(product.quantity));
```

Comment: Thanks. The segmentation fault is gone but the program still skip the quantity after i input the price, not allowing me to input the quantity.

Comment: What item do you try to add? GST or non-GST?

Comment: Replace %.2f with %f and report back, think about why it happened

Answer (score 0):

Your program crashes because of these lines:

```
scanf("%.2f",product.price);
scanf("%d", product.quantity);
```

scanf expects a pointer but you provide a double and an integer. Change these lines to:

```
scanf("%.2f",&product.price);
scanf("%d", &product.quantity);
```

And it will not crash. Also, you are trying to update a file but you open it  as read only:

```
fopen("gst.txt", "r");
```

If you want to write to the file, you should use:

```
fopen("gst.txt", "ra");
```

Comment: Thanks. The segmentation fault is gone but the program still skip the quantity after i input the price, not allowing me to input the quantity.

Comment: I have tried changing r to ra but the file is still not manipulated.

Comment: It's working now, I changed to a instead of ra. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed your segmentation fault and tested your program. Your `scanf` usage was the source of the problem.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Product//declaring a structure
{
    char code[25];
    //variables inside a structure
    char name[25];
    double price;
    int quantity;
};

int main(void) {
    struct Product product;
    int add;
    FILE *fptr;
    FILE *nfptr;

    printf("-------------------------------\n");
    printf("    ADD ITEM\n");
    printf("-------------------------------\n");
    printf("1.GST Items\n");
    printf("2.Non-GST Items\n");
    scanf("%d", &add);

    switch (add) //start of switch statement
    {
        case 1:
            fptr = fopen("gst.txt", "wr"); //open file
            if (fptr == NULL)//checking whether the file is empty or not
            {
                printf("File cannot be found\n");

            }
            else //else statement
            {
                printf("Add Item Code:\n");
                scanf("%s", product.code);
                printf("Item name:\n");
                scanf("%s", product.name);
                printf("Item price:\n");
                scanf("%.2lf", &product.price);
                printf("Item quantity:\n");
                scanf("%d", &product.quantity);

                fprintf(fptr, "%s;%s;%.2f;%d\n", product.code, product.name, product.price, product.quantity);
                fclose(fptr);
            }//end else statement
            break;

        case 2:
            nfptr = fopen("ngst.txt", "r"); //open file
            if (nfptr == NULL)//checking whether the file is empty or not
            {
                printf("File cannot be found\n");

            }
            else //else statement
            {
                printf("Add Item Code:\n");
                scanf("%s", product.code);
                printf("Item name:\n");
                scanf("%s", product.name);
                printf("Item price:\n");
                scanf("%.2lf", &product.price);
                printf("Item quantity:\n");
                scanf("%d", &product.quantity);

                fprintf(nfptr, "%s;%s;%.2f;%d\n", product.code, product.name, product.price, product.quantity);
                fclose(nfptr);
            }//end else statement
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem still occurs. I corrected my scanf already but the execution still skips the quantity not allowing me to input the quantity. The file is not manipulated as well.

Comment: @CareenHo If I try `scanf("%lf", &product.price);` then I could input price `80` and quantity 2, but I didn't check yet for decimals. It seems we can't specify decimals and that we must consume the newline character, that's why the program didn't stop.

Comment: it's working now but there's another problem. This program is suppose to caused the input to be showed in a show inventory menu but there's is no changes. Means that it does not manipulate the file.

Comment: You can't open a file in mode `"rw"`. As far as I know, there is no such thing. Also, why mention `r` at all when you're writing to it? The correct mode for appending data is `"a"`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks so much! It's working now! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with the code is that it opens the file in read mode, and then tries to write to it.  To append data to a file, use append mode (`"a"`).